# Refactor all code files to remove type qualifiers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

**Imagine this scenario:**
You open a Visual Studio solution that contains multiple projects and a whole lot of C# code. Some old code that you have never seen before. You need to remove all redundant type qualifiers without having to go throug the code manually. What do you do??

I have seen other people suggest using search-and-replace but thats not very pratical. My solution contains a lot of projects and files. A lot of it is old code that I know for sure contains a whole lot of redundant qualifiers. Its like the old developder had some sort of OCD with using type qualifiers.

**How can I remove all type qualifiers in the whole solution?** I have tried all sorts of refactoring extensions that can manipulate my code in a bunch of ways... but none of them can figure out how to change

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeObject> myList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeObject>(); 
var item = new MyApp.Controls.Models.Car();
```

to

```
List<SomeObject> myList = new List<SomeObject>(); 
var item = new Car();
```

Comment: I install Resharper and get that to do it for me.

Comment: I tried that but Resharper cant do what im asking. Resharper can refactor redundant type qualifiers when you are at the line in the code. Im searching for: "Right click solution -> Remove all redundant type qualifiers" or somehow during a "Cleanup code" extension.

Comment: Without a 3rd party tool you have to stick with find/replace and then fix the build errors with adding the usings accordingly

Comment: But im asking for the 3rd party tool :) Is there a tool that can help me?

Comment: Resharper *can* do that. When you're at the line, hit ALT+ENTER and get the actions you can perform, highlight that action and go RIGHT. You will get a new menu allowing you to perform the refactoring in varying scopes. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Context_Actions.html#scope

Comment: Yes thats the best solution so far... But as I said. I have a lot of files and I dont know where and what redudant qualifiers there are. I would have to open up all files to ensure I have succeded in removing them all.

Comment: No, you don't have to open all the files. Resharper has an option to remove all redundant qualifiers for an entire solution (as per the link posted by JSteen). It also has [code cleanup functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Cleanup__Index.html) which works over entire solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont click option go to the arrow and find Arrange qualifiers everywhere in solution.

You can do it for most of fix. Not just remove redundant qualifier. Use resharper.

[image]

Comment: By doing that I will remove the redundant qualifier for that specific type and only that. So still have to open all files and check to see if there are new redundant qualifiers I have not yet discovered. Seems like this might be the best solution. But not great.

Comment: @Christian It will remove All !